# Ping multiple docker containers from one container without going inside the container

Tags: shell, docker, ping

I'm working on a script where i'm trying to ping all the containers in my network. I need to SSH to a VM, enter a container and start pinging other containers. The list of VM and docker containers are coming from an array in my script.

The SSH without docker exec is working as of now.

```
for i in "${dockerName[@]}";
do
    echo -e "Running in $i container"
    IFS=':' read -ra containerName <<< "$docker_list"
    ssh -n -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$node "for name in \"${containerName[@]}\";do echo -e \"--$name\" done"
done
```

if i include command to enter the docker container, the script fails

```
ssh -n -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$node docker exec -it ${i} "for name in ${containerName[@]} ; do echo -e \"Pingning \$name \"; done"
```

Comment: What's your actual end goal with this?  (Are you trying to build your own orchestration and health-checking system, or is inter-container ICMP traffic actually important on its own?)

Comment: yes... i was wondering the same thing ...

Comment: David i'm trying to build my own orchestration script.